# It's time to start calculate the sum of badges that user earned by K

Tags: feature-request, badges

Jon Skeet has as of today 1067 bronze badges  (and I wish: Keep it up),

more respected to show a **1K** display style .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if it works the same way as rep, it would change at 10K (which will take quite a while to reach).

I'm not personally bothered either way, although I'd still want to be able to see the exact number myself, obviously.

If/when I reach 1000 silver badges (again, a long way off) it's more likely to start causing display wonkiness. I'm very happy for the SO team to defer worrying about this until that point :)

Comment: By that point, we'll need to think about putting an 'M' after your rep score. ;)

Comment: Nearly 8 years later, this 'long way to go' seems an awfully long time 'ago'.